# Compare Values from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sum, comparison

## Current Method:

### Current Query 1

```
SELECT
a.user,ui.contact_fname, ui.contact_lname,a.uid, COALESCE(pu.name,'N/A') AS UserPolicy,COALESCE(count(ea.user_ack),0) AS ack_count
FROM master_access.accounts a
RIGHT JOIN master_events.events_cleared ea ON a.uid=ea.user_ack
INNER JOIN master_biz.user_information as ui on ui.uid=a.uid
LEFT JOIN `master`.policies_users pu ON (a.template_id=pu.policy_id AND a.template_id!=0)
WHERE YEAR(ea.date_ack)=YEAR(NOW()) and MONTH(ea.date_ack)=10 and a.uid in (120,119,125,128,123,117,122,118,121,127)
GROUP BY a.user
ORDER BY COUNT(ea.user_ack) DESC
```

### Current Query 1 - Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0oOq.png)

### Current Query 2

```
SELECT
a.user,ui.contact_fname, ui.contact_lname,a.uid, COALESCE(pu.name,'N/A') AS UserPolicy,COALESCE(count(ea.user_ack),0) AS ack_count
FROM master_access.accounts a
RIGHT JOIN master_events.events_active ea ON a.uid=ea.user_ack
INNER JOIN master_biz.user_information as ui on ui.uid=a.uid
LEFT JOIN `master`.policies_users pu ON (a.template_id=pu.policy_id AND a.template_id!=0)
WHERE YEAR(ea.date_ack)=YEAR(NOW()) and MONTH(ea.date_ack)=10 and a.uid in (120,119,125,128,123,117,122,118,121,127)
GROUP BY a.user
ORDER BY COUNT(ea.user_ack) DESC
```

### Current Query 2 - Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O18kz.png)

### Desired Output

Basically adding the two outputs into one view, adding the values, if the "User ID" matches. Could someone please assist with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `master_access.accounts` table as a base. LEFT JOIN both queries to it. Filter rows where at least one subquery row matches. Build output columns list.

```sql
SELECT *        -- build needed columns list
FROM master_access.accounts
LEFT JOIN ( {query 1 text} ) AS subquery1 USING (uid)
LEFT JOIN ( {query 2 text} ) AS subquery2 USING (uid)
WHERE COALESCE (subquery1.uid, subquery2.uid) IS NOT NULL
```

In the output list - take `uid` column without table alias rather than all another columns.

Comment: So my query ended up looking like this:

Comment: It works when:
`SELECT acc.user,acc.uid        -- build needed columns list
FROM master_access.accounts AS acc
LEFT JOIN ( {query 1 text} ) AS subquery1 USING (uid)
LEFT JOIN ( {query 2 text} ) AS subquery2 USING (uid)
WHERE COALESCE (subquery1.uid, subquery2.uid) IS NOT NULL`

But it doesn't work when:
`SELECT acc.user,subquery1.contact_fname        -- build needed columns list
FROM master_access.accounts acc
LEFT JOIN ( {query 1 text} ) AS subquery1 USING (uid)
LEFT JOIN ( {query 2 text} ) AS subquery2 USING (uid)
WHERE COALESCE (subquery1.uid, subquery2.uid) IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Never mind I figured it out thanks :
`SELECT acc.user,COALESCE(sq1.contact_fname,sq2.contact_fname),COALESCE(sq1.contact_lname,sq2.contact_lname).....`

Thanks for the help